# Case in elisp, How to compare against a string?

Tags: emacs, elisp

```
(defun test:case (INPUT)
  (case (quote INPUT)
    ("a" (message "bar"))
    (otherwise (message "foo"))
    ))
(test:case "a")
```

I'm looking to get a case structure that compare "a" against INPUT and calls `(message "foo")`.
I cant get the code above to call anything but `(message "foo")`.

I must be doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to use `cond` in this case. `case` compares using `eql` which will compare the actual objects. In this case they will be two different strings and therefore it always evaluates the `otherwise` clause.

Using cond you can specify which equality operator to use e.g.:

```
(defun test:case (INPUT)
  (cond
    ((equal INPUT "a") (message "bar"))
    (t (message "foo"))))

(test:case "a")
```

Have a look at the available [elisp equality predicates](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Equality-Predicates.html#Equality-Predicates) and how they behave.

Comment: If you do not know where `INPUT` comes from it is better to use `string-equal`. Text properties are ignored by `string-equal`.

Answer (score 9):

If you have Emacs 24, `pcase` also works for comparing strings, and might be more readable than a long `cond` expression.

```
(defun test-case (input)
  (message
   (pcase input
     ("a" "bar")
     ("b" "baz")
     ("c" "quux")
     (_ "foo"))))
```

The matching rules for `pcase` are more complex but also much more general and flexible than `case`, resembling pattern-matching in ML or Haskell.

Answer (score 2):

1. `(message (if (equal INPUT "a") "bar" "foo"))`
2. You do not want to quote the first parameter to `case` - that makes no sense. If you quote `INPUT` then the result of evaluation is the symbol `INPUT`, **always**. And in that case, `case` is useless, since there is never more than one case (in this case, the `otherwise` case).

   You are **always** testing equality (using `eql`, but that is not the point here) of the string `"a"` and the symbol `INPUT`. That is always false, so with your original code you always see the message `foo`.